# Porque é que "giro" é bonito, engraçado, adorável, etc.?

Tags: etimologia

[***Giro***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/giro) (aumentativo, [*giraço*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/gira%C3%A7o)) significa em Portugal bonito, engraçado, aprazível, e sei lá que outras qualidades boas mais. Este [artigo no *Expresso*](http://expresso.sapo.pt/blogues/bloguet_lifestyle/Avidadesaltosaltos/nao-se-diz-giro-que-e-feio=f865452) explica melhor.

Como é que isto aconteceu? Os dicionários põem este significado de *giro* junto com os restantes (movimento circular, passeio curto) e dizem que vem do grego *gýro* via latim *gyro*. Mas isto não ajuda muito, porque este significado deve ser recente, já que não existe no Brasil, nem sequer vem no [Aulete](http://expresso.sapo.pt/blogues/bloguet_lifestyle/Avidadesaltosaltos/nao-se-diz-giro-que-e-feio=f865452).

Então como e quando é que *giro* adquiriu este significado?

Comment: Certa vez, em Portugal, uma mulher me disse "tu és muito giro".  Sem entender e sem querer admitir a minha ignorância, eu ri.  Algum tempo depois ouvi a palavra novamente e perguntei o significado.  Posso dizer que 99% dos brasileiros nunca ouviram essa gíria, que acredito ser exclusivamente portuguesa.

Comment: Que mulher atiradiça, heim! É sabido aqui em Portugal que *giro* não é conhecido no Brasil.

Comment: Pois é, e eu perdi uma... oportunidade.

Comment: Só cuidado com a forma feminina GIRA. Talvez pensem que você está falando de pomba-gira. Algo como uma pomba endemoniada ou em que desceu um espírito que fica girando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui encontrar nada conclusivo. O Houaiss, na entrada <sup>3</sup>*giro* com significado «palavra polivalente que qualifica pessoas ou coisas com atributos positivos», data-a de 1946 (com referência a [*Aldeia (Terra, Gente e Bichos)*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/aldeia-terra-gente-e-bichos/oclc/3093013) de Aquilino Ribeiro) e sobre a etimologia diz:

> orig.controv.; há quem vincule a <sup>1</sup>*giro*, talvez por ext. de sentido de ‘círculo’ como algo fechado, acabado, perfeito

Answer (score 0):

Tambem existe a palavra gira no feminino, que vem de girar. Pensei se nao poderia querer dizer, neste caso uma mulher atiradiça, que gira pelas ruas, pelos companheiros...
E talvez o adjecyivo giro tenha surgido por acrescento

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências.